# What is the motivation behind the solution of this problem involving complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem is

> Suppose for three distinct complex numbers $a, b, c$ such that $|a|=|b|=|c|>0$ all of the three numbers $a+bc, b+ac, c+ab$ are purely real. Prove that $abc=1$

By playing with the identities, I came up with a solution. Let $|a|=|b|=|c|=r$. Then $a+bc$ is real iff:

$$a+bc=\overline{a}+\overline{bc}=\frac{r^2}{abc}\left(bc+r^2a\right)\tag1$$

Thus,

$$\frac{r^2}{abc} = \frac{a^2+abc}{r^2a^2+abc}=\frac{b^2+abc}{abc+r^2b^2}=\frac{c^2+abc}{abc+r^2c^2} \tag2$$

where $(2)$ is obtained by simply solving $(1)$ for $\frac{r^2}{abc}$ and multiplying the denominator and numerator of the fraction obtained by $a$.

Rewriting $(2)$, using the properties of ratios:

$$\frac{r^2}{abc} = \frac{a^2+abc}{r^2a^2+abc}=\frac{b^2+abc}{abc+r^2b^2}=\frac{(a^2+abc)-(b^2+abc)}{(a^2r^2+abc)-(b^2r^2+abc)}=\frac{1}{r^2}$$

which gives $r^4=abc$. Taking the modulus of both sides gives $r^4=r^3$ which implies $r=1$ and so $abc=1$.

I hit upon this solution after an hour or so of trying and even that was by blind luck. Even after solving this, I can't understand the motivation behind the solution and why this particular way of manipulation succeeded.

Is there any intuition behind this solution? Why does this particular method work?

Comment: Sorry, why can't we just take $a,b,c=2$ (or any other real number).

Comment: @lulu That's true, but it's a bit of a degenerate case: you get a $0/0$ cancellation in the last equation.  I think it can be excluded by just requiring $a,b,c$ to be distinct (which also prevents them from all being real).  This causes $\{a^2,b^2,c^2\}$ to take at least 2 distinct values, which should allow the argument to go through without $0/0$ cancellations.

Comment: @ErickWong  Makes sense.

Comment: @lulu: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention (as Erick Wong has already pointed out) that the complex numbers should be distinct.